# How to create an activity and attach it to an existing WindowManager

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, window, android-windowmanager

I am trying to create a WindowManager with some LayoutParams,create an activity and attach the latter to it.

I know I could create the activity first and then get the Window in which it was created and then apply the parameters like so

```
myActivity.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

But can it be done the other way around?

Comment: You should never be instantiating Activities yourself with `new`. It will not work. Android needs to do additional setup with the Activity before it can function properly, and there's no way for you to do that instead of the OS.

Comment: I am not instantiating activities with `new`, I create a new intent and after that I do some additional work in onCreate(). I've also tried to do what is on my previous question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31302883/dismissing-a-custom-incoming-call-screen-on-android-when-the-call-is-answered-or by calling `wm.addView(ly, params);` but I am not able to get onCreate() executed because I am inflating a view only which is less than what I want to perform.